# What are these '@' signs in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried looking online related to redux or redux-actions which is used by the open source project, but I can't find out what the '@' is for (try searching for the @ sign, not too helpful):

`export const LIKE_POST = '@post/LIKE_POST';`

Can anyone shed some light? From the [busy](https://github.com/busyorg/busy/blob/develop/src/client/post/postActions.js) github (file linked to). I don't see anything mentioned in the [redux-actions](https://redux-actions.js.org/api) page either.

Also, if you care to tell me how the dispatch to `LIKE_POST` is getting received anywhere, because that string `LIKE_POST` is not found in the [reducer file](https://github.com/busyorg/busy/blob/develop/src/client/post/postsReducer.js), or anywhere else in the project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The '@' is probably just to signal that it is a library action. Basically, it's just to distinguish your own actions from the library actions.

But it doesn't mean more than that, it could be `export const LIKE_POST = 'post/LIKE_POST';` and it will still work.

You can notice similar action naming convention in `react-router-redux` for example.